# Why is the total count of Noah's life 950 years when the year of the flood took a full year cycle?

Tags: time, parashat-noach, mabul, noach-noah-the-man

The Posuk says that Noah was 600 years when he went into the Teivah (Bereshit 7:6,11). Rashi ([Bereshit 8:14](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=9168&p=3&showrashi=true#v14)) and the rest of the Mefarshim say that the flood took an entire year to complete. The Posuk then says that Noah lived another 350 years after the flood (Bereshit 9:28). That should put his final age at 951. Why then does the Torah (Bereshit 9:29) say he died at 950?

I have a feeling that that I heard once that the flood wasn't counted as part of the cycle of the world but I am not sure if that will help define a persons total age.

Comment: Maybe it means 600 years after the start of the flood?

Comment: @DoubleAA could be, but the narrative doesnt sound like that. It says he exited and lived 600 years after the flood. Sounds like afterwards! But maybe youre right!

Comment: It seems you got it backwards - 600 before and 350 after. Perhaps the year of _Mabul_ paralleled end of 600 and beginning of 350.

Comment: Maybe it was into the 350th year and into the 600th year, so 349.5+599.5=950

Comment: Possibly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10997

Comment: [This answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8466/1569) could fit this case according to the comments

Comment: I believe there is a peirush which says Noach did not age during the flood.

Comment: @sam can you clarify what that means? Less white hairs?

Comment: I heard once that Noach didn't slept the entire year. He was busy to feed the animals. So that year he "was not living", therefore it is not counted.

Comment: Perhaps consider marking an answer as correct if you like it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Moshav Z'keinim (Breishis 25:27) writes that the year in the teiva wasn't reckoned in Noach's age because the natural order of the universe wasn't functioning.

> אלא שנה שהיו בתיבה לא חשיב לפי שלא שמשו סדרי בראשית

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36593/4794

Answer (score 1):

Noah was 600 years old when the Flood started (**Bereshit 7:6**). **Bereshit 7:11** gives the exact start date of the Flood as the 17th day of the 2nd month of Noah's 600th year. To clarify, this means that from Noah's birth to the Flood, he had lived 599 full years and was now 1 month and 17 days into his 600th year.

The Flood waters increased on the earth for 150 days (**Bereshit 7:24**) after which they began to subside (**Bereshit 8:2-5**).

After the Flood (after 150 days), Noah lived 350 years (**Bereshit 9:28**), for a total of 950 years (**Bereshit 9:29**), which means that the Flood ended before the end of Noah's 600th year, it ended on the 17th day of the 7th month of Noah's 600th year. In other words, from Noah's birth to the end of the Flood, he had lived 599 full years and was now 6 months and 17 days into his 600th year. Although Noah was in the Ark for 370 days (**Bereshit 7:11-12, 24; 8:4-16**), the Flood lasted 150 days.

Noah was indeed 950 years old when he died.