# How could Yehoshua hold up the sky without the consequences in the natural order?

Tags: halacha-theory, talmud-gemara, miracle, parshanut-theory, yehoshua-joshua

I heard one explanation of this passage in Sefer Yehoshua, that the "stopping" of the sun had to do with the ceasing of its light. Yehoshua arrives at Giv'on at night, and thus Yehoshua prays for the extension of the night, rather than the extension of the day, which was covered by the hail prior to his prayer. Makes sense.
At the same time, according to Aztec lore in Mexico, the sun failed to rise for a whole day in the "City of the Gods", Teotihuacan (north of Mexico City). Likewise, it failed to rise for 20 hours in the Andes, according to Inca legends.
Since an "endless day" and an "endless night" are the same phenomenon in opposite sides of the world, this would seem to confirm the biblical account of the sun standing still at Giv'on.

Wouldn't the calendar be affected if the sun stood on the sky for 24 hours?

Comment: So? What is the point of your question? Of course the calendar was affected by the various changes in the length of the day. However, the number of dasys in the month was not affected.

Comment: וַיַּעֲמֹ֤ד הַשֶּׁ֙מֶשׁ֙ בַּחֲצִ֣י הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם וְלֹא־אָ֥ץ לָב֖וֹא כְּי֥וֹם תָּמִֽים The sun stood in the middle of the sky, and did not move to set for a full day. Not at night.

Comment: In what way would the calendar be affected? Please edit to clarify

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10997/170

Answer (score -6):

Actually, the sun did not stand still for Joshua at Gibeon. Gersonides felt that Joshua was speaking figuratively, that it was a wonder that he defeated the five nations in a single day before the sun had set. In his Guide of the Perplexed 2:35, Maimonides says that Joshua was singing a song about the sun standing still.

The Aztec myth tells us a story when Tecuciztecatl and Nanahuatzin volunteered to become the sun and moon. When Tecuciztecatl (as the sun) refused to rise, the plumed serpent god Quetzalcoatl sacrificed the gods so that the sun may rise. This suggests (according to the Aztec myth) that people need to make sacrifices.

I will add that the Aztec myths do talk about the sun standing still over the "City of the gods", Teotihuacan, as well as the Incas. However, neither Aztec nor Inca empires existed during the time of the Bible and no other nations in that time recorded such an observation.

Also, there is no evidence that the sun stood still. I have written extensively debunking the claim of Mr. Howard Hill. He does not work for NASA and the story was copied from a Christian story by Prof Totten.

It follows that the calendar was not effected.