# Teshuva that halachot don't apply off of earth

Tags: halacha, outer-space, responsa

Around the time of the ill-fated shuttle mission STS-107 (the space shuttle mission that Ilan Ramon was on), I heard a shiur about the laws of space travel. One of the sources presented was from a rabbi who penned a teshuva wherein he argued that halacha does not apply off of planet earth. I remember it being from a 20th century source (I suppose the question was really purely theoretical until then anyway). This decision was not accepted by anyone else and several people wrote in opposition, but I really would like to know who the author of the original teshuva was. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43683/7539) and [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23402/7539), this idea was put forth by Rabbi Ben-Zion Firrer in an article in the 5730 issue of *No'am*.

A copy of the article is available [here](http://www.kby.org/english/kiddush-hachodesh/?id=330); a discussion of the opinion, including Rabbi M. M. Kasher's opposition, can be found [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=Y4SPB17NkzAC&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=Rabbi+Ben-Zion+Firrer&source=bl&ots=GJIBSc_qyx&sig=wuSmdGJ1d6uMa1c_C_dlzlKy2ZU&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHrfm75NXNAhUF0xoKHYXkDGwQ6AEIFTAA) (*Contemporary Halakhic Problems*, R' J. David Bleich, vol 1, p211-212).