# Shmittah in Space

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, agriculture, shmita

Inspired by [this question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73457/teshuva-that-halachot-dont-apply-off-of-earth)

There are certain halachos, such as Shmittah, which only apply in Eretz Yisrael. My question is: is it a din in the *land* of Eretz Yisrael or the *airspace* of Eretz Yisrael? A nafka minah would be a space farm that's locked in orbit directly above Eretz Yisrael. Would the farmers aboard have to observe Shmittah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shmita is a law of the **land** of Israel, not of the airspace above it.

A proof is that plants grown through [hydroponics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics), i.e., with their roots outside of the soil, are not subject to the restrictions of Shmita (see e.g., [here](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1121/hydroponics/#footnotes) footnote 12 and [there](http://dinonline.org/2017/06/27/questions-regarding-hydroponics/) question 4).

Also, the biblical source for shmita speaks explicitly of the land

> Six years you shall sow your **land** and gather in its yield; but in the
>   seventh you shall let it rest and lie fallow. (Shemot [23:10-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.23.10-11?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en))
>
> When you enter the land that I assign to you, the **land** shall observe a
>   sabbath of the Lord. Six years you may sow your field and six years
>   you may prune your vineyard and gather in the yield. But in the
>   seventh year the **land** shall have a sabbath of complete rest, a sabbath
>   of the Lord: you shall not sow your field or prune your vineyard. You
>   shall not reap the aftergrowth of your harvest or gather the grapes of
>   your untrimmed vines; it shall be a year of complete rest for the
>   land. (Vayikra [25:2ff](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.25.2?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en))

Comment: There's a great debate based in the formulation of the Rambam regarding whether it's an Issur on the Gavra or on the Karka.