# Are hydroponics obligated in Maaser and Terumah

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, maaser-tithes, yoreh-deah, teruma

According to Halacha, are crops grown in hydroponics in Eretz Yisrael obligated in the laws of Terumah and Maaser? Or no, since it is grown off the ground in hydroponics systems is it exempt?

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2017/06/27/questions-regarding-hydroponics/

Comment: If your only concern is that it's disconnected from the ground, early sources already talk about that (מצע מנותק)

Comment: highly relevant: [Shmittah in Space](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92783/11501)