# Do we use a fixed clock interval or the Sun to define the concept of "day"?

Tags: halacha, time, sunset-shekia

Follow up on the [Earth stopping rotation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106337/if-earth-stopped-rotating-would-we-keep-shabbos) question.

What if instead of stopping, the Earth simply slowed down or sped up its rotation rate ([as it has, historically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_rotation#Changes))?

Do we halachically count a single calendar day as passing using A) a fixed length of time, e.g. 24 hours  or B) using the Sun's apparent position in a certain location [e.g. Jerusalem] to make a full cycle. or C) some other possibility.

To illustrate, let's say the Earth starts rotating 2x as fast. If A is true, then we'd still be counting seven 24-hour periods between one Shabbos and the next, but we'd have 14 sunsets during that time. If B is true, then from one Shabbos to the next would be seven 12-hour periods.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this type of question is a type of "riddle" that would involve fantasy analysis and is beyond our scope.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, since we see that every person on every day in every location slices his halachic day into 2 sets of 12 hours.

In Israel this *hour* can be as short as 50 minutes on your watch, in winter or as long as 70 minutes on your watch in summer.

Comment: @DanF Since when are fantastical questions off-topic? I’m voting to close as unclear, since none of these are actually how Day is determined.

Comment: @DanF@DonielF  I've modified the question to make it more clear

Comment: @DanF No fantasy analysis required. The earth's rotation is indeed continuously slowing down.

Comment: @DannySchoemann that sounds like an easy answer to me. (Could be slightly improved with a source that defines שעות זמניות, but that's up to you.)