# Shabbat in Alaska?

Tags: shabbat, synagogue, zemanim, geography, chutz-laaretz

How does that work?
My husband wants to go to Alaska for at least a few weeks. He even dreams of living there some day.

How is Shabbat celebrated in Alaska? Do they have any synagogues there? If so are they Orthodox and what times do they celebrate Shabbat?

Comment: [Asked and answered.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/shabbat-in-the-arctic)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26934/759

Comment: Not the same question, not a satisfactory answer.I asked "How and when do Alaskan Jewish people celebrate Shabbat" . Not asking for Star K's website times. I want an answer from a Jewish Alaskan. Thanks

Comment: Also doesn't the Zohar speak to the way the earth rotates and how there is a place where the sun goes down for months at a time even before secular science and explorers knew about it? Where is that written?

Comment: @RebeccaBurns "How is Shabbat celebrated in Alaska?" Jews in Alaska celebrate Shabbat with special prayers, lighting candles, eating meals with two loaves of bread, Kiddush, and abstaining from work. They do so following times determined by solar events and/or as described on the Star-K website. It's remarkably the same as everywhere else. I spent a Shabbat in Alaska and didn't feel confused at all. If that's not what you want to know, you should clarify. Note as well if you are interested in specific parts of Alaska you should specify them explicitly. Alaska is quite a big place.

Comment: [Kosher Travel In Alaska](http://www.alaska.org/advice/kosher-travel-in-alaska) gives the details for anchorage. Anchorage is a key stop for both cruises and land tours--and it's also home to Alaska's only orthodox synagogue. The Lubavitch Jewish Center in Anchorage - which is officially named the Esformes Jewish Campus of Alaska - was established in 1991 by Chabad emissaries Rabbi Yossi and Esty Greenberg.  It is Alaska's only Orthodox congregation. http://www.alaskajewishcampus.org/

Comment: Thank you so much sabbahillel! You have been helpful and resourceful! I am so happy to see a reliable source from a Real Jew who Knows about Alaska. Thank you so much for kindly answering my question!

Comment: @RebeccaBurns arguably limiting the question to what Jews do, and not what they theoretically ought to do, renders the question off topic as it would be about Jews, not Judaism itself.