# Is visiting Antarctica permitted for a Jew?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, geography, travel

Antarctica can have very short days or very short nights. [As discussed elsewhere on this site, finding the right time to pray can be difficult.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5240) Is it permissible to visit places like this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7182/759

Comment: or maybe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5240/759 or http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8282/759

Comment: "Does this mean he prays 3 times a year or is it not permissible to visit places like this?" I smell a [false dichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma)...

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think either 7182 or 5240 would be fair dupe targets for this.

Comment: There might be a difference that could be brought out here: the other questions address what you do if you're in those places, and by implication that means people go there, but maybe there's still halacha saying you shouldn't go (but if you do anyway, do the things already covered).  Craig, if you want to take this question in that direction go ahead and edit.  Otherwise it'll likely be closed as a duplicate.  (Either's fine with me; just offering options.)

Comment: You can close. I didn't know this question has been addressed. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited. What do y'all think?

Comment: @msh210 I like that. When I first saw the question on the Twitter stream I thought that it was indeed referring to the initial permissibility.

Comment: @msh210 I find the current wording quite boring. If your rabbi rules a certain way for you, then why can't you go there? If your rabbi won't rule and leaves you in a safek and you will have to skip certain prayers/rites/etc. then you probably shouldn't go there if you can help it, but either way you're asking your rabbi anyway! Deciding between halachik positions is your rabbi's job and if you have to go to one of these places, that is what they'll do.

Comment: This reminds me of the orthodox Jew who goes to visit outer space. When he returns he says he is sooo tired, He explained, Shacharis, Mincha, Maariv,  Shacharis, Mincha, Maariv, Shacharis, Mincha, Maariv, ........

Comment: @msh210, works for me.  Is it permissible to go to a place where you know there's doubt about prayer at all?  For certain reasons (which)?  This seems a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 3):

[Chabad](http://www.israelhayom.com/site/newsletter_article.php?id=3175) has no problem with Jews visiting Antartica.

Comment: Interesting that the article doesn't mention that the Tanya has already been printed in Antarctica, several decades ago.

Comment: Well, Rabbi Alfasi has none, anyway.

Comment: But he was going for a devar mitzva (I guess that's what you'd call that). So there isn't a proof that you could go for devar reshus.