# How would you keep shabbos in space?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, outer-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does somebody living in space (e.g. ISS) observe Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/when-does-somebody-living-in-space-e-g-iss-observe-shabbat)

If someone lived in outer space, either on a space station or a planet, for an extended period of time (or was even born there) how would that person keep shabbat or other mitzvot based on Earths relationship to the Sun and Moon?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5240/shachris-in-the-dark/5243#5243

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/when-does-somebody-living-in-space-e-g-iss-observe-shabbat